# Dockerfiles build performance issues

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile

The following Dockerfiles takes more than 30 minutes to build.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev libstdc++ && \
    apk add --no-cache g++ && \
    ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install allure-behave && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt
entrypoint ["sh", "testsuite.sh"]
```

Requirement file:

```
behave==1.2.6
boto3==1.8.2
botocore==1.11.9
pandas==0.25.0
```

Is that normal?